# Problems with LIKE query on PHP files

Tags: php, android, mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I am working on an Android app that connects to an sql database through php files. Currently I am having problems with the like function on one of my queues.

Here is the code of the file where the problem is:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db) or die("connection failed");

$like = $_REQUEST['like'];

$sql_q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '$like'");

if($sql_q)
{
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_q))
    {
        $output[] = $result;
    }
    if($output)
    {
        print(json_encode($output));
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code works with this query - SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '11/02/__/00/%' - and returns:

```
[{"ID":"11\/02\/00\/00\/00\/0\/0\/0","Value":"Tradicionais","Value_Complete":""},     
{"ID":"11\/02\/01\/00\/00\/0\/0\/0","Value":"Caipis","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/02\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Daiquiri","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/03\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Gin Tonico","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/04\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Long Island Ice Tea","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/05\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Manhattan","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/06\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Margarita","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/07\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Martini Seco","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/08\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Black Russian","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/09\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"White Russian","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/10\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Sex on the Beach","Value_Complete":""},    
{"ID":"11\/02\/11\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Sidecar","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/12\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Sakerinha","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/13\/00\/00\/1\/0\/0","Value":"Tequila Sunrise","Value_Complete":""},
{"ID":"11\/02\/14\/00\/00\/0\/0\/0","Value":"Vodka","Value_Complete":""}]
```

The same query returns this in phpMyAdmin:

[image: working sql query result]

However, the same code does not work with the query - SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '$like'. It returns an empty result set but in phpMyAdmin returns:
[image: not working sql query result]

I just can't figure out the issue here... Even this - SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '%'- returns nothing, when it should return everything.

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: In summary are you saying that the query works in phpmyadmin and not mysqli_query?

Comment: Yes. I can't figure out why...

Comment: Can you post the exact query that is executed, I mean can you echo it and paste it here, the one that works in PHPmyadmin but not in code

Comment: Never build your sql like that. Use prepared statements. You open up to sql injection attacks, because arbitrary code can be supplied through `$like`.

Comment: Here it is - SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '%11/02/__/00/%%'. I added the % before and after the var like as suggested (%$like%).

Comment: What do the contents of `$_REQUEST['like']` actually look like? One possible problem could be that PHP's `magic_quotes` feature is enabled so that any literal `%` in your input becomes `\%` instead which would remove its wildcard powers and match a literal `%` only

Comment: @Artjom B. Prepared statements? What do you mean? Use a var instead of string?

Comment: I agree with ArtjomB. (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) but can you try wrapping the fields and tables into a single quotes

Comment: This echo echo "like - " . $_REQUEST['like']; gives like - 11/02/01/__/00/%. So there is no change in the like var.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t have much time right now. I´ll try using the prepared statements and post my results here. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Add `%` to the variable

```
"SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '$like%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your query:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db) or die("connection failed");

$like = $_REQUEST['like'];

$sql_q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '%".$like."%'");

if($sql_q)
{
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_q))
    {
        $output[] = $result;
    }
    if($output)
    {
        print(json_encode($output));
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: will you please explain, exactly what you want to do.?

Comment: I want the queries to work. In phpMyAdmin they all work, but in the  files some don't, wich is the case of - SELECT `ID`, `Value`, `Value_Complete` FROM `products` WHERE `ID` LIKE '11/02/01/__/00/%'.

Comment: may be there is some spacing issue when you pass value for like constraint in query.

Comment: just try to print before executing query.

Comment: You're replicating the same SQL injection security vulnerability in the OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

Basically like in something work as equal to (=) but it give you the flexibility to use wild card. % wild card use to define in sql query that there is something but not matter.

If you are not use % with your query it means you are searching same string that is stored in $like variable.

In phpmyadmin you don't need to use %. Because phpmyadmin is designed to the make the use of database easy. So when you select like in search option it automatically add % before applying query on database.

Due to this reason you see these difference.

Comment: Ok, but I am using %. The like variable already has the % character. And this %$like% gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this this complete solution according to your requirements

```
SELECT tablename FROM id WHERE FIND_IN_SET('/',$column name);
```

It uses the `find_in_Set` mysql function which takes 2 parameters, one is the separator and the other is the column name.